# Javascript Syntax with [...] in front of a function call / constructor call

Tags: javascript

I have found a syntax in javascript I have never
seen before and I was unable to find the right
documentation.

It comes from a tutorial:

```
var connection = new [webkit|moz]RTCPeerConnection(...)
```

I can find by myself what webkit means and what moz means,
presumably these are two defined constants or enums.

but my question is:

What does the syntax `[webkit|moz]` mean in those squared brackets?

Is is some kind of typecasting the result of the function result?

And what does the `|` character mean in `[webkit|moz]` - is this the OR operator?

thx

Answer (score 4):

That's not proper javascript syntax (if you try running it, you'll get an unexpected token error at the first `[`), It just means you have to use either in your code, ie.:

```
new mozRTCPeerConnection()
```

for Firefox, and

```
new webkitRTCPeerConnection()
```

for webkit based browsers.

See the MDN docs on [RTCPeerConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection):

> Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for the proper prefixes to use in various browsers.

and

> Warning: RTCPeerConnection and RTCSessionDescription are currently prefixed in most browsers. You should include a polyfill if you're using it in any work.

Comment: Infact i've found this: window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection

Answer (score 2):

As @doldt said it's not js syntax, just a pseudocode indication.
You can use a kind of polyfill to instantiate the correct one:

```
var PeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection)

Answer (score 2):

This was taken from Mozilla developer network:

> Warning: RTCPeerConnection and RTCSessionDescription are currently
>   prefixed in most browsers. You should include a polyfill if you're
>   using it in any work. For instance:

```
var PeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
```

Take a look to the documentation at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection